# Unable to run a mixed-version program in flutter beta despite following official instructions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, intellij-14, dart-null-safety

I have an existing project that I want develop into a web app, so I switched to the flutter beta channel.  And since I also intend later to refactor my code for null-safety I started upgrading as many package dependencies as are available with null-safe revisions.  For now my project has to be a mixed-version program.

I have followed the official [Migrating incrementally and Testing or running mixed-version programs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety) instructions but my IDE (IntelliJ) is still riddled with Dart Analysis null-safe errors and my project fails to build because of the same errors. (I have invalidated caches and restarted IntelliJ, to no effect.)

I have set the minimum SDK constraint in pubspec.yaml to `2.12.0-0`; I've added `// @dart=2.9` to the top of all Dart files I don’t want to consider for null-safe analysis at this point in the migration, including main.dart; and I am using the `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety` command.

Can someone recommend what can be done to run my project as a mixed-version program?